# Could a Resource Manager and Node Manager in the same node? [MapR]

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, mapr

We have a node where Resource Manager and Node Manager are both running. Is that recommmended?

[image]

Comment: When you run hadoop in Psuedo distributed mode, all daemons run on the same machine but in difference JVMs. So yes, you can run RM and NM on the same machine. That is not recommended when you have a full-fledged cluster because it's good to have them on separate machines to avoid failures etc. But you can run them on a single machine in a cluster too.

Comment: @philantrovert Thank you for your answer. 
We have a cluster of 8 nodes, and we have some problems in excusion of  some jobs on Yarn (they take too much time and stop the processing of others) . Do you think that running NM and RM on the same machine is the reason of this issue?
Who recommend to use separatly the RM and NM ? Is that from a distribution or just a rule to follow ?

Answer (score 1):

The Resource Manager and the Node Manager can run on the same node **provided it has enough memory**.  If the memory you've allocated to both services plus the memory you've allocated to the rest of the services and daemons running on that node exceed the host's memory you could trigger OOMEs and have applications killed by the Linux OOM killer.

For most distributions it's not a recommended practice.  Running the RM and NM on separate nodes provide better memory and CPU isolation.  The NM in particular allocates work to containers and these require memory so if you've oversubscribed your nodes by using up all the memory to run services, you won't have any memory left to run your containers.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html